# VB.Net type conversion from string

Tags: vb.net, types, type-conversion

This is my first attempt at writing an oop program in vb.net.  The basic idea of the program is to use an excel sheet as a datasource and then update a mysql database.  To practice the principles of OOP I have created a type called motorbike and financeExample.

I am using the following connection string which takes the data as text only simply because there seems to be an issue reading the model 1198.

```
Dim xcelConnString As String = 
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
    & "Data Source=R:\newBikeUpdates\motorcyclesLatest.xls;" _
    & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0; IMEX=1"""
```

So I am reading the values in and then assigning them to the properties of the the motorbike and financeExample objects.

With a grounding in vbscript it became very clear very quickly that data typing is not as easy as I first thought.  So I therefore have written a function that will return the correct type at the point of assigning a value to a property:

```
motorcycle.category = checkValue(xcelDA("Category")) ' String expected
motorcycle.weight = checkValue(xcelDA("Weight")) 'String passed and Integer should be returned.
```

So here is the function:

```
Function checkValue(ByVal v As Object)
    Dim ret
    If Not IsDBNull(v) Then
        If Double.TryParse(v, ret) Then
            Debug.WriteLine("v is Double")
            Return ret
        ElseIf Integer.TryParse(v, ret) Then
            Debug.WriteLine("v is an Integer")
            Return ret
        ElseIf v.GetType Is GetType(String) Then
            Debug.WriteLine("v is a string")
            Return CStr(v)
        Else ' Presumption of string type
            Debug.WriteLine("v is Other")
            Return v
        End If
    Else
        Debug.WriteLine("v is DBNull")
        ret = ""
        Return ret
    End If
End Function
```

and the string element works for Category and a string is returned.  But when it gets to assigning the weight value, I get a string of "417" passed in and yet neither of the double.tryparse(v,ret) or integer.tryparse(v,ret) elements seem to work.  VS2010 reports v as a string/ system.string when using debug as v.getType().  I have even tried in debug passing in integer.tryParse("417",ret) and this works but for some reason it doesnt with the v parameter.

I have also tried integer.tryParse(v.toString,ret) and this doesn't work either.

So can anybody point me in the right direction please on how to conquer this issue, as CInt doesn't seem to work (VBscript grounding, sorry!)

Many thanks in advance!
Graham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so its fair to say that my heritage in vbscript is shining through in this question.

When running through and debugging the code and inspecting the value of v at the point I thought "417" was being passed in, I noticed that the value actually being passed in was "417 ", with the extra space.

Of course in vbscript I am pretty sure a trim would have automatically taken place.  So trimming the string at the point of calling the function actually returns a double as expected.

Don't laugh, I am realise what a plank I am!

If you looked thanks,
Graham

Comment: well I was just going to post a comment saying "works fine for me!" I basically passed "451" as param to checkValue.

Comment: Thanks for looking anyway.  I am still running into type conversion issues.  Is there any advice you may be able to give on this subject and how it can be best approached.